# Get column name of error `Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type varchar.`

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a stored procedure; when I execute it, I get an error

> Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type varchar

Is there is way to find the column that caused this issue? I have the T-SQL. Checking columns one by one is very tedious for us because we have lots of columns (legacy system).

Comment: _is there is way to find the column name that causes this issue_ No, not yet. Similar to this https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/339410/please-fix-the-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated-message-to-give-the-column-name which you should consider voting for.

Comment: You're out of luck. I'd generate the length of the data instead of the data and cross-reference it with the column schema

Comment: Sadly it seems that MS has no intention of fixing this hideous issue. It screams of lazy developer code and they are seemingly unwilling to fix it. It so absurd because obviously at the time is happens the engine knows what column(s) caused the error. OP - sad to say but you are stuck doing this the hard way.

Comment: May be SQL Server not showing column due to security issue like we have here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fp47G4MQFvA?

Answer (score 1):

There are many options to address and prevent the error, based on the prodedure's T-SQL, but the answer to your question is "No". MS Does not make the offending column information available.

HTH,
Sean